# How to use gganimate() in combination with geom_lines() so that the animation shows lines converging towards one of the lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2, animation, visualization, gganimate

I have this code producing this plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
time_points <- rep(1:10, times = 5)
class <- rep(letters[1:5], each = 10)

# Set different means for each class
class_means <- c(0, 5, 10, 20, 30)
outcome_values <- rnorm(50, mean = rep(class_means, each = 10), sd = 1)

# Create dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  time = time_points,
  class = class,
  outcome = outcome_values
)


ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = time_points, colour = class, y = outcome))
```

[image: some geom_line plot]

I want to use `gganimate` to create an animation in which the lines 'converge' towards one of them. It could be the mean, or, in this simple plot, I would like the lines from classes a,b,d and e to 'slide' towards c. When they reach c, all other lines disappear. My idea would to be to use this to animate how different lines converge to one other line, which for my case in mind would be the mean.

Is this even possible with gganimate?

Thanks!

Comment: example code does not match; e.g `class_labels` is not defined.

Comment: By what mechanism show the lines converge to one? I think you're leaving something out of your description.

Comment: @JonSpring Apologies! Issue solved now.

I would like them to move 'in parallalel'. So, imagine you could select the line of class a, and parralellaly move it until it reaches the line c (actually, the movement could not be exactly parallel; else it would never match c exactly). And then do the same with lines b, d, and e. Does this make it clearer? I edited the description a bit (I don't mean the number one, but one of the lines in the plot!)

Comment: It sounds like you want a linear interpolation between each value and c's value, like `y = (1-t)(orig_y) + t(c_y)`, where t goes from 0 to 1? So it doesn't use any sort of statistical process to get us there, but rather just slides the lines straight there?

Comment: Yes! For the transition, th lines in between the original 'a' and 'c' don't need to have any meaning. By converging I mean 'visually slide towards c', not any sort of statistical convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(gganimate); library(tidyverse)
df |>
  crossing(t = seq(0, 1, length.out = 100)) |>
  mutate(outcome2 = (1-t)*outcome + t*outcome[class == "c"], .by = time) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = time, colour = class, y = outcome2)) +
  transition_time(t)
```

[image]

Or just for curiosity:

```
df |>
  crossing(t = seq(0, 1, length.out = 2)) |>
  mutate(outcome2 = (1-t)*outcome + t*outcome[class == "c"], .by = time) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = time, colour = class, y = outcome2)) +
  transition_states(t) +
  ease_aes("bounce-out")
```

[image]